# Tabulator download has no styles at all

Tags: tabulator

I have included the style : true when using the tabulator. download but the downloaded html has only the data. No styles or table boarders. I'm using the latest 4.8 version. Any idea why is this happening ?

table. download ( "html", "a. html", {style:true})

Answer (score 0):

The HTML download will return a simple HTML table without any styling, that is the whole purpose of that download method.

If you are hoping for a more stylised output then i would recommend using the PDF downloader.

If you need the table to be a stylised output then you can always look at extending the download module to add your own downloader. the [Module Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/modules#module-download) has more info on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you ! I end up using the getHtml function and that gave me all the styles